# Import a class variable from another module

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import just a variable inside a class from another module:

```
import module.class.variable 
# ImportError: No module named class.variable

from module.class import variable 
# ImportError: No module named class

from module import class.variable
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (the . is highlighted)
```

I can do the following, but I'd prefer to just import the one variable I need.

```
from module import class as tmp
new_variable_name = tmp.variable
del tmp
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
variable = __import__('module').class.variable
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this will import the whole module? Equivalent to `import module` then `variable = module.class.variable` ?

Comment: Except that it won't bind any name to the imported module. Which is fine; `from module import clazz` "imports the whole module" too, *in exactly the same way*. There's simply no way around this; the class definition can't be guaranteed to make any sense without the rest of the module's context, and similarly for attributes of the class.

Comment: @Alex It will always be imported the *whole* module (but it depends on your statement *what* will be available in your scripts scope). `from x1 import x2` will load `x1` and then look where to find `x2`, either in the scope of `x2` or as a sub-package.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that -
the import statement can only bring elements from modules or submodules - class attributes, although addressable with the same dot syntax that is used for sub-module access, can't be individually imported.

What you can do is:

```
from mymodule import myclass
myvar = myclass.myvar
del myclass
```

Either way, whenever one does use the `from module import anything` syntax, the whole module is read and processed.The exception is

```
from module.submodule import submodule
```

, where, if thesubmodule itself does not require the whole module, only the submodule is processed.

(So, even onmy workaround above , `mymodule` is read, and executed - it is not made accessible in the global namespace where the import statement is made, but it will be visible, with all its components, in the `sys.modules` dictionary.

Comment: Your workaround looks remarkably similar to my workaround! Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Follow these two steps

1. Import the class from the module

   `from Module import Class`
2. Assign new variables to the existing variables from the class

   `var1=Class.var1`

   `var2=Class.var2`